# Are Gameboy Color games compatible on Pokemon Stadium 1

Tags: pokemon-stadium

I was wondering whether Gameboy color games are compatible on Pokemon Stadium 1, or is it only compatible with Pokemon stadium 2.

Comment: I vaguely remember using it with the 1st, but don't take my word for it just yet.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The English version of [Pokemon Stadium 1](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_Stadium_%28English%29) (which was actually Pokemon Stadium 2 in Japan) is compatible with the generation 1 games. That would be Red, Blue (Green in Japan), and Yellow. [Pokemon Stadium 2](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_Stadium_2) (called Gold and Silver in Japan) is compatible with both the first generation of games, and the second (Gold, Silver and Crystal).

As a side note, the Japanese Pokemon Stadium 1 (sometimes called [Pokemon Stadium 0](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_Stadium_%28Japanese%29) outside Japan) was only compatible with 42 of the original 151 Pokemon from the first generation.